# Output Error:Binary to decimal java

Tags: java, string, binary

The aim of my code was to convert binary numbers(String)n to decimal form
This program segment compiled succesfully but the output is coming way bigger than expected.

Need some help.Thanks in advance

```
public class bindecstr {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s="11111";
    int l=s.length();
    double sum=0;
    int t=l-1;
for(int i=0;i<l;i++){   
    char ch=s.charAt(i);
    int x=(int)ch;
    double d=(Math.pow(2,t-i))*x;
    sum=sum+d;
}
System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some specific changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `s.charAt(i)` is a character *code* of the digit, not its numeric value. the UNICODE code point for `'0'` is `U+0030`; for `'1'`, it is `U+0031`.

Change to

```
int ch=s.charAt(i) - '0';
```

to fix the problem ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/a2Kgx2)). The reason this works is that the code points of digits are arranged sequentially. Subtracting the code point of zero from a code point of another decimal digit produces "the distance" between that code point and the corresponding digit, which corresponds to the numeric value of the digit.

Comment: No change in the output

Comment: @user2511145 Then you are not doing it right (see the demo, the link is clickable; it's your fixed code, and it correctly prints 31).

Comment: I tried that and it worked.Can you suggest any way I might avoid the unicode hassle, because I'm still at the basics now

Comment: @user2511145 You can use the library for that, too, but that would defeat the whole purpose of your learning exercise. I's `sum = Integer.parseInt(s, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int x = (int) ch - '0';
```

Answer (score -1):

when you put  int x=(int)ch; 
the value that saved in x is not 1 its the corresponding unicode value that is 49 
so to take the real value of one you gonna need if statement in the for loop
`char ch=s.charAt(i);
    if(ch=='1')
       x=1
    if(ch=='0')
       x=0`